# Dokku: How to change the version of Elasticsearch in plugin

Tags: elasticsearch, dokku

I'm using dokku version 0.4.14
I've installed Elasticsearch via:
dokku plugin:install https://github.com/dokku/dokku-elasticsearch.git elasticsearch

but the default version is 1.7.1 and it also then runs elasticsearch 1.7.1, but I need to run 2.2.1

How is it possible to have elasticsearch 2.2.1 running via this plugin:
https://github.com/dokku/dokku-elasticsearch
?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not out of the box, since the docker folks seem to have made their image a bit less usable: https://github.com/dokku/dokku-elasticsearch/issues/23